# Unable to get the element's properties in chrome developer options

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm using selenium to automate a sample demo web site.

Site URL: http://demo.automationtesting.in/Register.html

If you leave the first name as blank and click submit button, you'll get a small pop-up saying "Please fill out this field". I'm unable to identify this element in `F12` - developer options in chrome, since as soon as I press `F12` the element is getting disappeared.

Can anyone help me in finding the XPATH of this element?

Comment: Press f12 first then try to find that element

Answer (score 0):

That is the default validation of chrome. It is shown due to the html 5 attribute [`required`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-required-attribute) that is on the `<input>`.